# A man on the top of the tower, standing on the sea.

Tags: trigonometry

A man on the top of the tower, standing in the seashore finds that a boat coming towards him makes 10 minutes to change the angle of depression from $30$ to $60$. How soon will the boat reach the seashore. 
[image]

My Attempt, 
We know, Speed $=\frac {dist. }{time }$
                               $=\frac {CD}{10}$.

Also,  $Tan 60=\frac {AB}{BC}$
$\sqrt {3}=\frac {AB}{BC}$
$AB=\sqrt {3} BC$.

Now, what do I have to do further?

Comment: You need to assume the boat is travelling at a constant velocity.  The problem would change if the boat was moving due to a rope which the man in the tower was pulling at a constant rate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the side length of $CB $ is $x $, then in $\triangle ABC $, we have length of $AB  =\sqrt {3}x $. Now in $\triangle ABD $, we have $BD =\sqrt {3}x \cot 30 =3x $. Thus $CD=2x $.

If the boat covers a distance of $2x $ in ten minutes, it can cover a distance of $x $ in what time?? Hope it helps. [image]

Comment: what is  $\triangle BD$??

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider $AB$ to be $h$. Then, 
$$
BD=\frac{h}{\tan30^\circ}=h\sqrt{3} \\
BC=\frac{h}{\tan60^\circ}=\frac{h}{\sqrt{3}}\\
CD=BD-BC=\frac{2h}{\sqrt{3}}
$$
If the speed of the boat is $x$ metres per second,
$$
CD=\frac{2h}{\sqrt{3}}=600x
\implies  \frac{h}{x\sqrt{3}}=300
$$ 
Time in which the boat travels distance $BC$ is :
$$
\frac{BC}{x}=\frac{h}{x\sqrt{3}}=300
$$
Hence, the boat takes $300$ seconds or $5$ minutes to reach the shore. In total, it takes $15$ minutes to cover distance $BD$